# Speeding up symbolic recursion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a backwards recursion for a binomial tree. At each node an unknown `C` enters in such a way that at the starting node we get a formula, `A(1,1)`, that depends upon `C`. The code is as follows:

```
A=sym(zeros(1,Steps));
B=zeros(1,Steps);
syms C; % The unknown that enters A at every node
tic
for t=Steps-1:-1:1

 % Values needed in A and B
 Lambda=1-exp(-(1./S(t,1:t).^b).*h);
 Q=((1./D(t))./(1-Lambda)-d)/(u-d);
 R=normcdf(a0+a1*Lambda);

 % the backward recursion for A and B
 A(1:t)=D(t)*C+D(t)*...
     (Q.*(1-Lambda).*A(1:t) ...
      + (1-Q).*(1-Lambda).*A(2:t+1));

 B(1:t)=Lambda.*(1-R)+D(t)*...
     (Q.*(1-Lambda).*B(1:t)...
      + (1-Q.*(1-Lambda).*B(2:t+1))); 
end

C = solve(A(1,1)==sym(B(1,1)),C);
```

This code takes around 4 seconds if `Steps = 104`. If however we remove `C` and set matrix `A` to a regular double matrix, it only takes about 0.02 seconds. Using `syms` thus increases the calculation time by a factor 200. This seems too much to me. Any suggestions into speeding this up?

I am using Matlab 2013b on a MacBook air 13-inch spring 2013. Furthermore, if you're interested in the code before the above part (not sure whether it is relevant):

```
a0 = 0.9;
a1 = -3.2557;
b = 1.2594;
S0=18.57;
sigma=0.6579;
h=1/104;
T=1;
Steps=T/h;
f=transpose(normrnd(0.04, 0.001 [1 pl]));
D=exp(-h*f); % discount values
pl=T/h; % pathlength - amount of steps in maturity

u=exp(sigma*sqrt(h));
d=1/u;

u_row = repmat(cumprod([1 u*ones(1,pl-1)]),pl,1);
d_row = cumprod(tril(d*ones(pl),-1)+triu(ones(pl)),1);
path = tril(u_row.*d_row);
S=S0*path;
```

Comment: Could you provide code including all required variables? I don't think there is much to improve but I'll take a closer look if I can run the code.

Comment: `f` is undefined, what is it? A factor of 200 isn't too bad if you realize what symbolic math is doing relative to floating point. But, yes, there are ways to speed things up. Is there a reason you're using symbolic math instead? One thing you can do that would probably speed up both version is remove all or parts of `Lambda`, `Q`, and `R` from the `for` loop – create vectors and index into them.

Comment: @Daniel: I indeed forgot to include the variable f. But it is now complete.

Comment: @horchler: I included f, my bad. Is there any other way to include unknown variables instead of symbolic math? The reason I use it is because I cant get C out of the recursion, which i tried in several ways. I'll try to take out 'Lambda', 'Q' and 'R' to see if this speeds something up.

Comment: `f` is a function of `pl` which is first defined two lines later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, there's no need to use symbolic math or use an unknown variable. You can effectively assume that `C = 1` in your recursion relation and solve for the actual value at the end. Here's the full code with some other improvements:

```
rng(1); % Always seed your random number generator

a0 = 0.9;
a1 = -3.2557;
b = 1.2594;
S0 = 18.57;
sigma = 0.6579;
h = 1/104;
T = 1;
Steps = T/h;
pl = T/h;
f = 0.04+0.001*randn(pl,1);
D = exp(-h*f);
u = exp(sigma*sqrt(h));
d = 1/u;

u_row = repmat(cumprod([1 u*ones(1,pl-1)]),pl,1);
d_row = cumprod(tril(d*ones(pl),-1)+triu(ones(pl)),1);
pth = tril(u_row.*d_row);
S = S0*pth;

A = zeros(1,Steps);
B = zeros(1,Steps);
tic
for t = Steps-1:-1:1
    Lambda = 1-exp(-h./S(t,1:t).^b);
    Q = ((1./D(t))./(1-Lambda)-d)/(u-d);
    R = 0.5*erfc((-a0-a1*Lambda)/sqrt(2)); % Faster than normcdf

    % Backward recursion for A and B
    A = D(t)+D(t)*(Q.*(1-Lambda).*A(1:end-1) + ...
                   (1-Q).*(1-Lambda).*A(2:end));
    B = Lambda.*(1-R)+D(t)*(Q.*(1-Lambda).*B(1:end-1) + ...
                            (1-Q.*(1-Lambda).*B(2:end))); 
end
C = B/A
toc
```

This take about 0.005 seconds to run on my MacBook Pro. There are certainly other improvements you could make. There are many combinations of variables that are used in multiple places (e.g., `1-Lambda` or `D(t)*(1-Lambda)`), that could be calculated once. Matlab may try to optimize this a bit. And you can try moving `Lambda`, `Q`, and `R` out of the loop – or at least calculate parts of them outside and save the results in arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out as soon as I can.

Comment: You were completely right. 'C' could simply be taken out of the recursion. Thank you!